# elementary proof for existence of point with minimal period 2 for entire function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, elementary-proofs

Fatou proved a very interesting result: 
for a transcendental entire function $f$, the second itarate 
$f^{2}$ has at least has one fixed point. 
(Using the technique of Picard theorem)

This result has been generalized by Rosenbloom:
$f^{n}$ has at least has one fixed point for every $n\geq 2$ (Using the technique of Nevanlinna theory)

Bergweiler proved a very strong version:
$f$ has infinitely many points of minimal period $n$, for each $n\geq 2$ (quite technical)

There may be little hope to expect a elementary proof for the general version.

I wonder whether there exist a elementary proof (without using Nevanlinna theory)
for the following theorem:
$f$ has at least one point of minimal period $2$.

Any reference and comments will be appreciated.

Comment: I edited your question. Do you agree with my changes?

Comment: @yaoxiao Could you clarify if Picard's Theorem is  allowed, so that Fatou's result may be applied to reduce the question to the assertion that the equation $$f\circ f(z)-z=e^{g(z)}(f(z)-z)$$  has no entire solutions unless $f$ is the identity?

Comment: @ Alexandre Eremenko, Dear professor, Thanks for your changes of the previous version of the question.